# Oracle Apex 5.1 - Theme Style, referenc custom image in custom css code

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'd like to use the theme styles to generate different CI for sub companies of our main company. I would like to insert every sub-companies logo into the top naviagtion bar. The plan was to have a seperate theme style for each sub company and within each style have a custom css code which sets the background image to a referenced static file (or theme file). Unfortunately the custom css code does not seem to evaluate the substitution strings so the images can not be rendered. e.g.

```
div.t-Header-logo {
background-image: url(#APP_IMAGES#COMPANY1_LOGO.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 250px; /*or your image's width*/
height: auto; /*or your image's height*/
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Is there any way to achive different logos per theme style?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# reference with it's resolved name in the CSS file.

e.g. **#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#add.gif** becomes-

```
http://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/wwv_flow_file_mgr.get_file?p_security_group_id=441224701954687600&p_fname=add.gif
```

Get the resolved name for your workspace by viewing page source, copy and replace #WORKSPACE_IMAGES# with the same. It will work.

Note: make sure that the image file you have uploaded is not specific to an application.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, it works with the full URL to the image, even though your solution is depreceated in Apex 5, you can just use a fully qualified URL. Would be nic if the substitution would work within the css area....